# Expression language and interfaces

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, el

I'm not an expert of JSTL and expression language, so my question may be silly...

I'm working with Spring MVC and in my controller I have:

```
@ModelAttribute("export_types")
public ExportType[] getExportTypes() {
    return edService.getTypes();
}
```

`ExportType` is a custom interface:

```
public interface ExportType {

    String getName();

    //...
}
```

In my page I have:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${export_types}">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="${item.name}"></td>
        <td>${item.name}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

But when I run my web app I get this expection: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String`

The strange thing is that the exception says `on type java.lang.String` and not in type `ExportType`. So my question is: **can't I use expression language with interfaces?**

---

**NOTE 1**

`edService.getTypes()` returns an `ExportType[]` array with concrete implementations of the interface.

Just for clarity, I have an abstract class that implements `ExportType` interface. Concrete Types inherit from this:

```
public abstract class AbstractExportType implements ExportType {
    protected String name;

    protected AbstractExportType() {
        this.name = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    //...
}
```

---

**NOTE 2**

The controller method that forwards to export.jsp is very simple:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getExportForm() {
    return "jsp/export";
}
```

Comment: `edService.getTypes();` what does this returns exactly  ?

Comment: Make sure that you don't overwrite `export_types` attribute somewhere.

Comment: What does your controller method that forwards to your JSP look like?

Comment: Use `${item.class}` instead of `${item.name}`. This will give you the type of the `item`. If it is indeed a `String`, then your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @doublep A concrete class could implement the `getName` method in a different way...

Comment: @axtavt is the first thing I thought, but unfortunately this is not my problem...

Comment: @davioooh In a different way how--it's still going to return a string. But I'm not sure how that's relevant, the issue is the type of `item`. That `ExportType` is an interface is irrelevant--all EL will do is try to call `getName()` on whatever `item` is. doublep's point was to make sure you're dealing with instances of the type you believe you are.

Comment: @DaveNewton When I say implement the method _in a different way_, I mean that the `name` returned may not be the Class name... However I think you're right. I have to verify the actual type returned by `getTypes()`. Thank you all guys.

Comment: Oh. Not really relevant to the question, though, I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with interfaces. Most likely as @doublep says, `export_types` isn't actually an `ExportType[]`. I've tried reproducing what you're doing and it works fine.

Comment: Ok, maybe there's something wrong with the returned array type. Thank you for your help!